# Extjs3.2 Grid Filter localy

Tags: extjs

I am working on extjs grid, I found that for filter we have to set local=false for remote. What I want once data is loaded into grid it filter from grid instead of hitting database every time.

How to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `local: true` property? If you set `local: false` will work remote data. The following is a sample from Sencha examples.

```
var filters = new Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters({
    encode: false, // // configure whether filter query is encoded or not (initially)
    local: true,   // defaults to false (remote filtering)
    filters: [{
        type: 'numeric',
        dataIndex: 'id'
    }, {
        type: 'string',
        dataIndex: 'company',
        disabled: true
    }, {
        type: 'numeric',
        dataIndex: 'price'
    }, {
        type: 'date',
        dataIndex: 'date'
    }, {
        type: 'list',
        dataIndex: 'size',
        options: ['small', 'medium', 'large', 'extra large'],
        phpMode: true
    }, {
        type: 'boolean',
        dataIndex: 'visible'
    }]
});
```